# How to update/reload Volley JsonArray cache with new data whenever data is available in server?

Tags: android, caching, android-volley

When cache is empty for first time, data is retrieved from server and loaded in cache and displayed in listview .Its working perfectly till here.
Problem is cache is always called thereupon and data from it is loaded into listview although there is new data in server.

Here is my code :

```
'Cache cache = requestQueue.getCache();
           Cache.Entry entry = cache.get(url, temp);
            if(entry != null){
                //Cache data available.
                try {
                    String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
                    Log.d("CACHE DATA", data);
                    JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(data);
                    homedata(jsonArray);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading from cache.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else{
                // Cache data not exist.
                onresumefunction();
            }'
```

Comment: The server should correctly set the caching headers in the HTTP response.

Comment: Like how .Can you explain please?

Comment: The HTTP protocol allows the server to indicate if content may be cached at the client and for how long it may be cached. See here for details: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-13

Comment: i have already gone through the link .dint understand properly.@Henry